# Redirect does not work anymore after installing IceFaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

In my JSF 2.0 project I've got an index.xhtml page where I implemented a login. After a successful login I want to redirect to EditFile.xhtml. This worked always successfully.

`<h:commandButton value="Login" action="EditFile.xhtml"/>`

Now I have installed the ICEfaces component and it doesn't work anymore, it only reloads the index.xhtml page. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi Dominik, what method are you using to redirect -- navigation-case or a redirect in code, ala: externalContext.redirect(destination); ?

Comment: i think wrote this a bit wrong...i do this with the login button -> <h:commandButton value="Login" action="EditFile.xhtml"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `h:commandButton` was never supposed to redirect by default (wondering how it ever worked before), so try:

```
<h:commandButton value="Login" action="EditFile.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"/>
```

or add the `<redirect/>` tag to your navigaton case.

Comment: sorry, i'm not the hero in english ;) the word that i mean was transmit...so the transmission worked without any problems till i added ICEfaces.
I'll try out your proposal, thank you!